# Pass std::chrono::duration by value or by reference to const?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, c++-chrono

So in the past I passed `std::chrono::duration` values by reference to const but now I think they are no more than a single arithmetic type wrapped in a class so it makes sense to pass it by value.

Has anyone profiled it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to specification, duration wraps a single variable (number of ticks) of type Rep specified in

```
template<
    class Rep, 
    class Period = std::ratio<1> 
> class duration;
```

so basically you can choose to handle copying/passing const ref as you would do for that Rep type.
When I previously used chromo::duration I chose it to be a long, and in that case I don't see a reason to pass by const reference, (especially when in my architecture a long and an address are both 8 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

> I think they are no more than a single arithmetic type wrapped

look at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) :

> The only data stored in a duration is a tick count of type Rep. If Rep is floating point, then the duration can represent fractions of ticks. Period is included as part of the duration's type, and is only used when converting between different durations.

and:

> where the tick period is a compile-time rational constant

Your guess is right